# Custom authentication asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, custom-authentication

I want to use a secret key (api key) authorization asp.net core web api. The key will be passed in Authorization header like given below,

```
ex. Authorization keytype;h43484344343bbhfdjfdfhj34343
```

I want to write a middleware to read this key from request headers and call an internal api to validate the key.

In web api we can write a message handler to do this, but I am new to asp.net core. I'm seeing a lot of samples but they are using inbuilt JWT token authentication. But I wanted to use my own key and I decrypt this key and validate against a database entry.

Can anyone suggest some code samples on how to do this?

Comment: What version of asp core are you using?

Comment: .net core 1.1 is my target framework

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have used this approach in a solution using asp core 1.1. First define a custom scheme:

```
public static class Authentication
{
    public const string Scheme = "Custom";
}
```

You then have to inherit `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>`. Here is where the logic for validating the header value will go:

```
public class MyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<MyOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var authorizationHeader = Context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!authorizationHeader.Any())
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Skip());

        var value = authorizationHeader.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Skip());

        // place logic here to validate the header value (decrypt, call db etc)

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob")
        };

        // create a new claims identity and return an AuthenticationTicket 
        // with the correct scheme
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Authentication.Scheme);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), new AuthenticationProperties(), Authentication.Scheme);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

In order to inherit `AuthenticationHandler` you must create an options class where you set the `AuthenticationScheme`-property to the scheme you are using:

```
public class MyOptions : AuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = Authentication.Scheme;
}
```

After this you have to inherit `AuthenticationMiddleware<TOptions>`. This will create the handler you implemented in the previous step:

```
public class MyAuthenticationMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<MyOptions>
{
    public MyAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<MyOptions> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UrlEncoder encoder) : base(next, options, loggerFactory, encoder)
    {
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<MyOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new MyAuthenticationHandler();
    }
}
```

In order to easily plug in your middleware you can define these extension methods:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder app, IConfigurationSection config)
{
    return app.UseMyAuthentication(options => {});
}

private static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<MyOptions> configure)
{
    var options = new MyOptions();
    configure?.Invoke(options);

    return app.UseMiddleware<MyAuthenticationMiddleware>(new OptionsWrapper<MyOptions>(options));
}
```

Then in your `Startup` class you can finally add your middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMyAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("MyAuthenticationOptions"));

    // other stuff

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Then add the `AuthorizeAttribute` on your actions specifying the scheme you just created:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = Authentication.Scheme)]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    // stuff ...
}
```

There are a lot of steps but hopefully this will get you going!

Comment: Do you have the whole code in somewhere like GitHub etc?

Comment: Hold on, I´ll put up a sample

Comment: 4+years later... or no sample

Comment: Weups my bad, here is a [sample](https://github.com/pellec/AspCoreCustomAuthenticationDemo) (old)

Comment: `AuthenticationScheme` no longer seems to be a property of `AuthenticationOptions` or the syntax in your example is incorrect, how do I specify the scheme now? Also, is the middleware still needed?

Comment: Check out this blog post on how to implement a custom authentication scheme in asp core 3.x: https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/implementing-custom-authentication-scheme-and-handler-in-aspnet-core-3x